# I install a matrimonial script, when i received a link of confirmation in email, it does not go to profile page

Tags: php

">" ##I install a matrimonial script, when i received a link of confirmation in 
 ">"email, it does not go to profile page.
  ">"After register, i received a message, (registration has been completed. An ">"email has been sent to yo to confirm the registration. After you will ">"confirm, >you will be able to create your profile) but
 ">"when i click the link it seems it try to do some thing in 3 seconds but in ">"a while it says, (Oooops, Your registration has not been successfully ">"completed....please follow the registration confirmation link properly to ">"complete your registration).##

">" ## the code of registration_confirmation.php is below,##

">"I need your good help, please #

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");

    $sqlsettings = "SELECT * from admin";
    $resultsettings = mysql_query($sqlsettings);
    $rowsettings = mysql_fetch_array($resultsettings);


    $msg = 0;

    if($_REQUEST['confirm']!=""){
        $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE 
    ConfirmationCode='".mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['confirm'])."' and 
    Status=0";      

        $result = mysql_query ($query);
        if(@mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
        {
            $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $query5 = "update users set Status=1 where 
     ConfirmationCode='".mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['confirm'])."'";

            $result5 = mysql_query($query5);
            $msg = 1;

            $_SESSION['UserID_reg']=$row['UserID'];
            $_SESSION['LoginID_reg']=$row['LoginID'];
            $_SESSION['EmailAddress_reg']=$row['EmailAddress'];
            $insert = "insert into user_profile(UserID) 
    VALUES(".$row['UserID'].")";

            $resultt = mysql_query($insert);

            $insert = "insert into partner_profile(UserID) 
    VALUES(".$row['UserID'].")";            

            $resultt = mysql_query($insert);

        }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sharara - Registration Confirmation</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registrationconfirmation.css">

    </head>

    <body topmargin="2" leftmargin="0" oncontextmenu="return false" 
    onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" marginheight="2" 
    marginwidth="0" background="images/background.jpg">


    <script language="javascript" src="js/matrimonials-v10.js"></script>
            <!-- The top link table start's here -->
            <center>

                <!-- The top link table starts here -->
                <div style="width: 762px;" align="right">
                    <?PHP
                    include("topheader.php");
                    ?>
                </div>
                <!-- The top link table ends here -->

            <!-- The topbanner table start's here -->
            <div style="width: 762px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 
    255);">
            <div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(143, 167, 191); border-
   left: 
    1px solid rgb(143, 167, 191); border-right: 1px solid rgb(143, 167, 
  191);">


                <!-- logo + banner space -->
                <div style="padding: 2px 0pt 4px 0px;">
                    <div style="padding: 4px 0pt 4px 16px; width: 215px; 
   float: 
    left; text-align: left;">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/matrimonial-logo-
    sm.gif" border="0"></a>
                    </div>

                </div><br clear="all">

            </div>
            <!-- logo + banner space -->

                    <div>
                    <div style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(143, 167, 191); 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; background-color: #000000;">
                    <div style="margin: 1px 0pt 1px 0px; padding: 3px 0pt 
   3px 
    0px; background-color: #990000;" class="mediumwhitebold">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- midlinks + services space end's here -->


            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The topbanner table ends here -->
            </center>

    <center>
    <div style="width: 762px;">
    <div class="mediumblack" style="border-style: solid; border-color: 
  rgb(143, 
    167, 191); border-width: 0px 1px 1px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) 
  none 
    repeat scroll 0%; -moz-background-clip: initial; -moz-background-origin: 
    initial; -moz-background-inline-policy: initial;">
        <div style="width: 760px;">
            <div style="width: 30px; float: left;"><br></div>
            <div style="margin: 0pt 0pt 10px 0px; width: 700px; float: 
  left;">
    <div style="float: left; text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;">

            <?PHP
        if($msg == 1){
        ?>
        <strong>Congratulations!</strong> Your Registration has been 
    successfully Completed...
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="profile1.php">Click here to create your profile now!</a> 
  your 
    profile will be shown in website after the approval from website 
    administration..
        <?PHP
        }
        else{
        ?>
        Oooops! Your Registration has not been successfully Completed... 
    Please 
    follow the Registration Confirmation Link propely to complete your 
    registration..
        <?PHP
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code with us?

Comment: this is the confirmation link i received, 
http://www.sharara.pk/registration_confirmation.php?confirm=e97bddcaa25f5b34db0e59bb092becbc

Comment: need your good favor...please

Comment: @mazedlx i add the code

Comment: `if($_REQUEST['confirm']!="")` should be `if ($_GET['confirm'] != "")`, also: replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_GET`

Comment: Hello, any expert is available to resolve the query...?

Comment: Besides all that, I would recommend that you take a look at [http://www.phptherightway.com/](http://www.phptherightway.com/). Your code is a perfect target fpr SQL injection.

Comment: @mazedlx: thanks for your interest, I wrote , on three places, request=get, still receiving same above message.....

Comment: do you get any results when you query `"SELECT * from users WHERE 
    ConfirmationCode='".mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['confirm'])."' and 
    Status=0";` manually in your database?

Comment: I need more help....

Comment: do you get any results when you query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE ConfirmationCode="e97bddcaa25f5b34db0e59bb092becbc" AND Status = 0;` directly in your database (either with mysql cli or phpmyadmin)?

Comment: @mazedlx.....ok i try

Comment: @mazedlx.....i received this....Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/kashif/public_html/sharara.pk/registration_confirmation.php on line 13

Comment: Dude, you should take a web development course. You need to open up phpmyadmin or any other tool to query the database directly and insert the above statement.

Comment: DEAR , i did what u said, the first code is getting error in phpmyadmin, the second code ran successfully, but the error i sent you received...

Comment: Ran successfully? Did you receive results?

Comment: no dear i received the above error.....

Comment: @mazedlx now no error , but same result....

Comment: any help please

Comment: Open PHPMyAdmin and query the database. If the user is not there, use breakpoints and print the output of $_GET and $_REQUEST before saving it to the database.